# Add files to existing component using joomla template

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding, components

I'd like to know if it is possible to add new files to existing joomla components using the installation process of a joomla template?

I created a template. In Joomla there are also some extensions installed. Can I use the template to add new files to the existing folder structure of a joomla component?

If this is not possible how should i add custom files to existing joomla components? As far as I understand - template overrides are only used to change already existing files from components.

Answer (score 0):

Template overrides are only used to replace existing layouts, but template alternative and alternate layouts do not need to have the same names and are located in your html folder just like overrides. (The difference between the two is whether they have an xml file; if the xml file is there it will show up in the list when creating menu items).

If you want to replace or add to a model or controller you will need to use a plugin, but that is considered somewhat of an advanced technique.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add the files to other components during installation but since your main template file is a php file you can perform the changes the instant the template is loaded in the front end.

Have a look at JFile to help you create files.

But be careful. It sounds like what you are doing is plain wrong. What are you trying to achieve?